# Can injective and projective model structures be the same ?

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, model-categories

Is there a non trivial example  where injective and projective model structures coincide ? By non trivial I mean an example of a functor category on a non discrete base category where I guess injective and projective model structure coincide, is it right ?

Best

Comment: I deleted my answer, it was wrong, as pointed out by Zhen Lin.

Comment: ok but my comment was right, isn't it ?